# Problema con SP Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Restaure un par de bases de datos de un ambiente 2005 a un ambiente 2012, al tratar de ejecutar un SP, me aparece el siguiente error:

codigo del SP de la linea 532 es el siguiente:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BO_GET_WEB_OC_CSV]
(   
   @OPCION SMALLINT,
   @ID_USUARIO NUMERIC,
   @ID_EMPRESA NUMERIC,    
   @LISTADO_ID_OC NVARCHAR(200)
)

AS

--VARIABLES DE LA TABLA SUBIR_OC PARA LA CONFIGURACION DE LA CREACION DE LA OC PLANO SIMPLE
DECLARE 
    @NUMERO_ORDEN BIT,
    @EAN BIT,
    @PLU BIT,
    @DESCRIPCION BIT,
    @CANTIDAD BIT,
    @CANTIDAD_SUBARTICULOS BIT,
    @IVA BIT,
    @IMPOCONSUMO BIT,
    @VALOR BIT,
    @CODIGO_PROVEEDOR BIT,
    @CABECERAS BIT,
    @TABULADOR BIT,
    @ANCHOFIJO BIT,
    @OTRO VARCHAR(1),
    @EAN_COMERCIANTE BIT,
    @TIPO_ORDEN BIT,
    @EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR BIT,
    @EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA BIT, 
    @ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL BIT,
    @EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS BIT,
    @EAN_PUNTO_VENTA BIT,
    @CANTIDAD_PUNTO_VENTA BIT,
    @PRECIO_BRUTO BIT,
    @PRECIO_NETO BIT,
    @TALLA BIT,
    @MARCA BIT,
    @COLOR BIT,
    @PRECIO_INFORMATIVO BIT,
    @INFORMACION_COMPRA BIT,
--VARIABLES PARA LOS QUERY DINAMICOS
    @STRSQL NVARCHAR(4000),
    @STRSQL2 NVARCHAR(4000),
    @PARAMETROS NVARCHAR(2000)                  

SET NOCOUNT ON

--TABLA TEMPORAL DEL DETALLE DE LA OC CON TODOS LOS CAMPOS
    CREATE TABLE #DETALLE
   (
        ID_DETALLE NUMERIC IDENTITY(1,1),
        ID_ORDEN NUMERIC,
        EAN_EMPRESA_COMPRADORA VARCHAR(35),
        NOMBRE_EMPRESA_COMPRADORA VARCHAR(70),
        COD_TIPO_ORDEN VARCHAR(3),
        DES_TIPO_ORDEN VARCHAR(35),
        NUMERO_ORDEN VARCHAR(35),
        EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR VARCHAR(35),
        NOMBRE_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR VARCHAR(70),
        EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA VARCHAR(35),
        NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA VARCHAR(70),
        F_MIN_ENTREGA VARCHAR(35),
        F_MAX_ENTREGA VARCHAR(35),
        F_SOL_ENTREGA VARCHAR(35),
        ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL VARCHAR(35),
        EAN_ITEM VARCHAR(35),
        PLU VARCHAR(35),
        CODIGO_ITEM_PROVEEDOR VARCHAR(35),
        DESCRIPCION_ITEM VARCHAR(70),
        EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS VARCHAR(35),
        NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS VARCHAR(70),
        CANTIDAD_TOTAL VARCHAR(10),
        EAN_PUNTO_VENTA VARCHAR(35),
        NOMBRE_PUNTO_VENTA VARCHAR(70),
        CANTIDAD_PUNTO_VENTA VARCHAR(50),
        PRECIO_BRUTO VARCHAR(17),
        PRECIO_NETO VARCHAR(17),
        IVA VARCHAR(17),
        VALOR_IMPOCONSUMO VARCHAR(35),
        TALLA VARCHAR(35),
        MARCA VARCHAR(35),
        COLOR VARCHAR(35),
        ID_CLIENTE NUMERIC,
        CANTIDAD_SUBARTICULOS NUMERIC,
        CONSECUTIVO NUMERIC,
        PRECIO_INFORMATIVO VARCHAR(35),
        INFORMACION_COMPRA VARCHAR(400)
    )

--TABLA PARA IDENTIFICAR EL REGISTRO UNICO DONDE SE DEBE ACTUALIZAR LA CANTIDAD TOTAL
--EN OC CROSSDOCKING
CREATE TABLE #IDMIN
(
   ID_ORDEN NUMERIC,
   CONSECUTIVO NUMERIC,
   IDMINIMO NUMERIC,
   CANTOTAL NUMERIC
)

--SE ASIGNAN LAS OPCIONES QUE VIENEN EN LA CONFIGURACION DEL CLIENTE EN SUBIR_OC
SELECT   
    @NUMERO_ORDEN=NUMERO_ORDEN,
    @EAN=EAN,
    @PLU=PLU,
    @DESCRIPCION=DESCRIPCION,
    @CANTIDAD=CANTIDAD,
    @CANTIDAD_SUBARTICULOS=CANTIDAD_SUBARTICULOS,         
    @IVA=IVA,
    @IMPOCONSUMO=IPOCONSUMO,
    @VALOR=VALOR,
    @CODIGO_PROVEEDOR=CODIGO_PROVEEDOR,
    @CABECERAS=CABEZERAS,
    @TABULADOR=TABULADOR,
    @ANCHOFIJO=ANCHOFIJO,
    @OTRO=OTRO,
    @EAN_COMERCIANTE=EAN_COMERCIANTE,
    @TIPO_ORDEN=TIPO_ORDEN,
    @EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR=EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR,
    @EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA=EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA,   
    @ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL=ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL,
    @EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS=EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS,
    @EAN_PUNTO_VENTA=EAN_PUNTO_VENTA,
    @CANTIDAD_PUNTO_VENTA=CANTIDAD_PUNTO_VENTA,
    @PRECIO_BRUTO=PRECIO_BRUTO,
    @PRECIO_NETO=PRECIO_NETO,
    @TALLA=TALLA,
    @MARCA=MARCA,
    @COLOR=COLOR,
    @PRECIO_INFORMATIVO=PRECIO_INFORMATIVO,
    @INFORMACION_COMPRA=INFORMACION_COMPRA
FROM   SUBIR_OC
WHERE   ID_USUARIO=@ID_USUARIO

--SE ARMA EL ENCABEZADO SEGUN LAS OPCIONES CONFIGURADAS POR EL CLIENTE
IF @OPCION = 1--PARA EL ENCABEZADO
   BEGIN
      --SI EL CLIENTE PIDE CABECERAS
      IF @CABECERAS = 1
         BEGIN      
             --ARMAMOS EL SELECT SEGUN LAS OPCIONES DEL CLIENTE
             
             SET @STRSQL = 'SELECT '
                --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL EAN_COMERCIANTE POR DEFECTO IRA EL NOMBRE_COMERCIANTE
             IF @EAN_COMERCIANTE = 1
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''EAN Empresa Compradora'',''Nombre Empresa Compradora'','        
             
             --SI ELCLIENTE CONFIGURA EL TIPO_ORDEN
             IF @TIPO_ORDEN = 1 
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Tipo Orden '','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL NUMERO_ORDEN
             IF @NUMERO_ORDEN = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Número de la Orden'','      
          
             --SI ELCLIENTE CONFIGURA EL EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR POR DEFECTO IRA EL NOMBRE_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR
             IF @EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''EAN Entidad a Facturar'',''Nombre Entidad a Facturar'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA POR DEFECTO IRA EL NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA
             IF @EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''EAN Lugar Entrega Factura'',''Nombre Lugar Entrega Factura'','
          
             --LA FECHA MIN Y MAX VAN SIEMPRE
             SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''F. Mínima Entrega'',''F. Máxima Entrega'','          
    
            --FECHA SOLICITADA--PERU
             SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''F. Solicitada de entrega'','

             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL
             IF @ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Acuerdo Promocional'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EAN
             IF @EAN = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''EAN del Ítem'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA PLU
             IF @PLU = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''PLU'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA CODIGO_PROVEEDOR
             IF @CODIGO_PROVEEDOR = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Código ítem proveedor'','
          
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA DESCRIPCION
             IF @DESCRIPCION = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Descripción del ítem'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS POR DEFECTO IRA EL NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS
             IF @EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''EAN Lugar Entrega Ítems'',''Nombre Lugar Entrega Ítems'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA CANTIDAD
             IF @CANTIDAD = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Cantidad Total'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL EAN_PUNTO_VENTA POR DEFECTO IRA EL NOMBRE_PUNTO_VENTA
             IF @EAN_PUNTO_VENTA = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''EAN Punto de Venta'',''Nombre Punto de Venta'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA CANTIDAD_PUNTO_VENTA
             IF @CANTIDAD_PUNTO_VENTA = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Cantidad Pto Vta'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA PRECIO_BRUTO
             IF @PRECIO_BRUTO = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Precio Bruto'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA PRECIO_NETO
             IF @PRECIO_NETO = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Precio Neto'','
          
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA IVA
             IF @IVA = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''% IVA'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA IMPOCONSUMO
             IF @IMPOCONSUMO = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Valor Impoconsumo'','
           
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA CANTIDAD_SUBARTICULOS

             IF @CANTIDAD_SUBARTICULOS = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Cantidad sub-artículos'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA TALLA
             IF @TALLA = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Talla'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA MARCA
             IF @MARCA = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Marca'','
    
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA COLOR
             IF @COLOR = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Color'','
             
              --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA PRECIO_INFORMATIVO 
             IF @PRECIO_INFORMATIVO = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Precio Informativo'','
             
             --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA INFORMACION_COMPRA 
             IF @INFORMACION_COMPRA = 1      
                SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + '''Observaciones'','
    
             SET @STRSQL = SUBSTRING(@STRSQL,1,LEN(@STRSQL) - 1)
            END --Fin CABECERAS
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @STRSQL = 'SELECT '''' '            
            END
        --Se ejecuta el select
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @STRSQL      
    END -- Fin OPCION Encabezado

--SE ARMA EL DETALLE SEGUN LAS OPCIONES CONFIGURADAS POR EL CLIENTE
IF @OPCION = 2--PARA EL DETALLE
   BEGIN      
     
      --21-Nov-2006:LadyG
        --INSERTAMOS EN LA TABLA TEMPORAL LAS OPCIONES BASICAS DE LA OC REFERENTE A ITEMS Y OC
      SET @STRSQL=N'INSERT INTO #DETALLE '+
            '( '+
                'ID_ORDEN, '+
             'EAN_EMPRESA_COMPRADORA, '+
             'COD_TIPO_ORDEN, '+
             'DES_TIPO_ORDEN, '+
             'NUMERO_ORDEN, '+
             'EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR, '+
             'EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA, '+
             'F_MIN_ENTREGA, '+
             'F_MAX_ENTREGA, '+
             'F_SOL_ENTREGA, '+
             'EAN_ITEM, '+
             'PLU, '+
             'CODIGO_ITEM_PROVEEDOR, '+
             'DESCRIPCION_ITEM, '+
             'EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS, '+
             'EAN_PUNTO_VENTA, '+
             'CANTIDAD_PUNTO_VENTA, '+
             'PRECIO_BRUTO, '+
             'PRECIO_NETO, '+
             'ID_CLIENTE, '+
             'CANTIDAD_SUBARTICULOS, '+
             'CONSECUTIVO, '+               
             'PRECIO_INFORMATIVO, '+
             'INFORMACION_COMPRA '+             
            ') '+
         'SELECT  ORDEN_COMPRA.ID_ORDEN, '+
                    'ORDEN_COMPRA.NAD_BY_COMPRADOR, '+
                    'ORDEN_COMPRA.ID_BGM_TIPO_MENSAJE, '+
                    'SUBSTRING(TM.DESCRIPCION,0,36), '+
                    'ORDEN_COMPRA.ID_BGM_DOCUMENTO, '+
                    'ISNULL(ORDEN_COMPRA.NAD_IV_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR,''''), '+
                    'ISNULL(ORDEN_COMPRA.NAD_ITO_ENTREGA_FACTURA,''''), '+
                    'ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ORDEN_COMPRA.FECHA_MINIMA,120),''''), '+
                    'ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ORDEN_COMPRA.FECHA_MAXIMA,120),''''), '+
                    --'ISNULL(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(35),ORDEN_COMPRA.FECHA_MINIMA,20),''-'',''''),'':'',''''),'' '',''''),0,13),''''), '+
                    --'ISNULL(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(35),ORDEN_COMPRA.FECHA_MAXIMA,20),''-'',''''),'':'',''''),'' '',''''),0,13),''''), '+
                    'ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ORDEN_COMPRA.FECHA_SOLICITADA,120),''''), '+
                    'ITEMS.EAN_ARTICULO_LIN, '+
                    'ISNULL(ITEMS.PIA_IN_COMPRADOR,''''), '+
                    'ITEMS.PIA_SA_CODIGO_EMPRESA, '+
                    'SUBSTRING(ITEMS.IMD_A_DESCRIPCION,0,70), '+
                    'ORDEN_COMPRA.NAD_DP_LUGAR_ENTREGA, '+
                    'ISNULL(LOC.NUMERO_LOCALIZACION,ORDEN_COMPRA.NAD_SN_PUNTOVENTA), '+
                    'CASE CAST(SUBSTRING(STR(ISNULL(LOC.QTY_CANTIDAD,''''),16,3),CHARINDEX(''.'',STR(ISNULL(LOC.QTY_CANTIDAD,''''),16,3))+1,3) AS INT) '+
                        'WHEN 0 THEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ISNULL(LOC.QTY_CANTIDAD,''''),16,0))),'''') '+
                            'ELSE ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ISNULL(LOC.QTY_CANTIDAD,''''),16,3))),'''') END,  '+

                    'CASE CAST(SUBSTRING(STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_BRUTO,0),16,4),CHARINDEX(''.'',STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_BRUTO,0),16,4))+1,4) AS INT) '+
                        'WHEN 0 THEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_BRUTO,0),16,0))),'''') '+
                            'ELSE ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_BRUTO,0),16,4))),'''') END, '+
                    
                    'CASE CAST(SUBSTRING(STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_NETO,0),16,4),CHARINDEX(''.'',STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_NETO,0),16,4))+1,4) AS INT) '+
                        'WHEN 0 THEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_NETO,0),16,0))),'''') '+
                            'ELSE ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_NETO,0),16,4))),'''') END, '+
              
              'ORDEN_COMPRA.ID_CLIENTE, '+
              'CAST(ITEMS.CANTIDAD_SUB_ARTICULOS AS NUMERIC(16,3)), '+
              'ITEMS.CONSECUTIVO '+ 
              ',CASE CAST(SUBSTRING(STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_INFORMATIVO,0),16,4),CHARINDEX(''.'',STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_INFORMATIVO,0),16,4))+1,4) AS INT) '+
                        'WHEN 0 THEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_INFORMATIVO,0),16,0))),'''') '+
                            'ELSE ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ISNULL(ITEMS.PRI_PRECIO_INFORMATIVO,0),16,4))),'''') END '+              
              ', ISNULL(ITEMS.FTX_INFORMACION_1,'''')+ISNULL(ITEMS.FTX_INFORMACION_2,'''')+ISNULL(ITEMS.FTX_INFORMACION_3,'''')+ISNULL(ITEMS.FTX_INFORMACION_4,'''')+ISNULL(ITEMS.FTX_INFORMACION_5,'''') '+              
      'FROM  OC_BO_V1_1.dbo.ORDEN_COMPRA ORDEN_COMPRA WITH (NOLOCK) '+
                'INNER JOIN OC_BO_V1_1.dbo.ITEMS ITEMS WITH (NOLOCK) '+ 
                        'ON ITEMS.ID_EMPRESA=ORDEN_COMPRA.ID_EMPRESA '+
                    'AND ITEMS.ID_ORDEN=ORDEN_COMPRA.ID_ORDEN '+
                'INNER JOIN OC_BO_V1_1.dbo.BGM_TIPO_MENSAJE TM WITH (NOLOCK) '+
                        'ON TM.ID_BGM_TIPO_MENSAJE = ORDEN_COMPRA.ID_BGM_TIPO_MENSAJE '+
                'LEFT OUTER JOIN OC_BO_V1_1.dbo.LOC_LUGAR_ENTREGA LOC WITH (NOLOCK) '+
                        'ON LOC.ID_EMPRESA  = ORDEN_COMPRA.ID_EMPRESA '+
                    'AND LOC.ID_ORDEN = ORDEN_COMPRA.ID_ORDEN '+
                    'AND LOC.CONSECUTIVO = ITEMS.CONSECUTIVO '+
      'WHERE ORDEN_COMPRA.ID_EMPRESA=@ID_EMPRESA '+
            'AND ORDEN_COMPRA.ID_ORDEN IN('+@LISTADO_ID_OC+')'
      --21-Nov-2006:LadyG:fin

      SET @PARAMETROS = N'@ID_EMPRESA NUMERIC '
      EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @STRSQL, @PARAMETROS,@ID_EMPRESA

        --SE IDENTIFICAN LOS IDENTITY MINIMOS PARA CADA ITEM (ESTO SE HACE PARA NO REPETIR LA CANTIDAD TOTAL EN TODOS LOS ITEMS)
        INSERT INTO #IDMIN 
      ( 
        ID_ORDEN,
        CONSECUTIVO,
         IDMINIMO, 
         CANTOTAL 
        )
        SELECT   
           ID_ORDEN,
         CONSECUTIVO,
         MIN(ID_DETALLE),
         --SE SUMAN LAS CANTIDADES POR PTO VTA PARA UTILIZARLA EN EL CASO QUE NO VENGA LA CANTIDAD TOTAL
         --EN OC CROSS DOCKING
         SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,CANTIDAD_PUNTO_VENTA))
        FROM #DETALLE
        GROUP BY ID_ORDEN,
                 CONSECUTIVO

        --SE ACTUALIZA LA TABLA TEMPORAL #CABECERA Y #DETALLE CON LA INFO DE LOS CAMPOS QUE CONFIGURO EL CLIENTE Y NO SE INSERTARON

        --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #CABECERA Y #DETALLE, PARA MOSTRAR SOLAMENTE LO CONFIGURADO POR EL CLIENTE
        SET @STRSQL2 = 'SELECT '

      --24-Nov-2006:Mafe:1
      --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL EAN_COMERCIANTE SE ACTUALIZA EL NOMBRE_COMERCIANTE
      IF @EAN_COMERCIANTE = 1      
         BEGIN
            UPDATE #DETALLE  
                SET NOMBRE_EMPRESA_COMPRADORA=SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(EMP.NOMBRE)),0,71)
            FROM #DETALLE #DET WITH (NOLOCK)
                    INNER JOIN EMPRESA EMP WITH (NOLOCK)
                        ON EMP.ID_EMPRESA = #DET.ID_CLIENTE 
      --24-Nov-2006:Mafe:1:FIN  
    
            --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON EL EAN DE LA EMPRESA COMPRADORA Y SU NOMBRE.
                --28-Sep-2006:Mafe:1
            IF @ANCHOFIJO=1 
               SET @STRSQL2= @STRSQL2 + 'cast(#D.EAN_EMPRESA_COMPRADORA as char(35)),cast(ISNULL(#D.NOMBRE_EMPRESA_COMPRADORA,'''') as char(70)) AS NOMBRE_EMPRESA_COMPRADORA,'
            ELSE
               SET @STRSQL2= @STRSQL2 + '''=T("''+#D.EAN_EMPRESA_COMPRADORA+''")'' AS EAN_EMPRESA_COMPRADORA,' + '''=T("''+ISNULL(#D.NOMBRE_EMPRESA_COMPRADORA,'''')+''")'' AS NOMBRE_EMPRESA_COMPRADORA,'
         END

      --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON LA DESCRIPCION DEL TIPO DE ORDEN
      IF @TIPO_ORDEN = 1
        BEGIN 
            IF @ANCHOFIJO=1
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(#D.DES_TIPO_ORDEN as char(35)),'
            ELSE
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '#D.DES_TIPO_ORDEN,'
        END

      --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON EL NUMERO DE LA OC
      IF @NUMERO_ORDEN = 1      
        BEGIN       
            IF @ANCHOFIJO=1         
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(#D.NUMERO_ORDEN as char(35)),'
            ELSE
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '''=T("''+#D.NUMERO_ORDEN+''")'' AS NUMERO_ORDEN,' 
        END

        --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR SE ACTUALIZA EL NOMBRE_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR
      IF @EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR = 1      
         BEGIN
            UPDATE #DETALLE 
                SET NOMBRE_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR=SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(SE.DESCRIPCION))+' '+RTRIM(LTRIM(SE.DIRECCION)),0,71)
            FROM #DETALLE #DET WITH (NOLOCK)
                    INNER JOIN SITIO_ENTREGA SE WITH (NOLOCK)
                        ON SE.ID_EMPRESA = #DET.ID_CLIENTE 
                        AND SE.EAN_NAD_ITO_DP = #DET.EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR

              --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON EL EAN DE LA ENTIDAD A FACTURAR Y SU NOMBRE.
                IF @ANCHOFIJO=1 
                    SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(#D.EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR as char(35)),cast(ISNULL(#D.NOMBRE_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR,'''') as char(70)) AS NOMBRE_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR,'
                ELSE    
                    SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '''=T("''+#D.EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR+''")'' AS EAN_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR, ISNULL(#D.NOMBRE_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR,'''') AS NOMBRE_ENTIDAD_FACTURAR,'
         END                                --'''=T("''+#D.EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA+''")'' AS EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA,

        --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA SE ACTUALIZA EL NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA
      IF @EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA = 1      
         BEGIN
            UPDATE #DETALLE 
                SET NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA=SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(SE.DESCRIPCION))+' '+RTRIM(LTRIM(SE.DIRECCION)),0,71)
            FROM #DETALLE #DET WITH (NOLOCK)
                    INNER JOIN SITIO_ENTREGA SE WITH (NOLOCK)
                        ON SE.ID_EMPRESA = #DET.ID_CLIENTE 
                        AND SE.EAN_NAD_ITO_DP = #DET.EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA                    
                
             --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON EL EAN DEL LUGAR DE ENTREGA DE LA FACTURA Y SU NOMBRE
             IF @ANCHOFIJO=1    
                    SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(#D.EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA as char(35)),cast(ISNULL(#D.NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA,'''') as char(70)) AS NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA,'
                ELSE
                    SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '''=T("''+#D.EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA+''")'' AS EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA, ISNULL(#D.NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA,'''') AS NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_FACTURA,'
         END  

      --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON LA FECHA MAXIMA Y MINIMA
       IF @ANCHOFIJO=1
            SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(#D.F_MIN_ENTREGA as char(35)),cast(#D.F_MAX_ENTREGA as char(35)),'
        ELSE    
            SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '''=T("''+#D.F_MIN_ENTREGA+''")'' AS F_MIN_ENTREGA,' + '''=T("''+#D.F_MAX_ENTREGA+''")'' AS F_MAX_ENTREGA,'--#D.F_MIN_ENTREGA,#D.F_MAX_ENTREGA,' 
                                -- 'ISNULL(#D.DESCRIPCION_ITEM,'''') AS DESCRIPCION_ITEM,'    
                                -- '''=T("''+#D.EAN_ITEM+''")'' AS EAN_ITEM,' 

      --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON LA FECHA SOLICITADA --PERU
      IF @ANCHOFIJO=1 
            SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(#D.F_SOL_ENTREGA as char(35)),'
        ELSE
            SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '''=T("''+#D.F_SOL_ENTREGA+''")'' AS F_SOL_ENTREGA,'

        --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL SE ACTUALIZA EL ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL
        IF @ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL = 1      
      BEGIN
         UPDATE #DETALLE
            SET ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL = RFF.ID_RFF_DOCUMENTO_REFERENCIA
         FROM #DETALLE #DET WITH (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN OC_BO_V1_1.dbo.RFF_DOCUMENTO_REFERENCIA RFF WITH (NOLOCK)
                    ON RFF.ID_EMPRESA = @ID_EMPRESA
               AND RFF.ID_ORDEN = #DET.ID_ORDEN
         WHERE RFF.ID_TIPO_RFF_DOCUMENTO_REFENCIA = 'PD'    
         
         --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON EL ACUERDO PROMOCIONAL
         IF @ANCHOFIJO=1
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(ISNULL(#D.ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL,'''') as char(35)) AS ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL,'
            ELSE
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'ISNULL(#D.ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL,'''') AS ACUERDO_PROMOCIONAL,'
      END


      --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON EL EAN DEL ITEM
      IF @EAN = 1      
        BEGIN
            IF @ANCHOFIJO=1
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(#D.EAN_ITEM as char(35)),'
            ELSE
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '''=T("''+#D.EAN_ITEM+''")'' AS EAN_ITEM,'
        END
    
    --print  @PLU
    --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON EL PLU DEL ITEM
      IF @PLU = 1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE #DETALLE SET
                PLU = CC.PLU_ARTICULO_PIA
            FROM #DETALLE #DET WITH (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN CEN_BO_V3_3.dbo.CODIGO_CLIENTE CC
                    ON CC.ID_CLIENTE = #DET.ID_CLIENTE
                    AND CC.ID_EMPRESA = @ID_EMPRESA
                    AND CC.EAN_ARTICULO_LIN = #DET.EAN_ITEM
            WHERE #DET.PLU = ''

            IF @ANCHOFIJO=1
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(#D.PLU as char(35)),'
            ELSE
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '''=T("''+#D.PLU+''")'' AS PLU,'
        END
        
        --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON EL CODIGO DEL ITEM DEL PROVEEDOR
        IF @CODIGO_PROVEEDOR = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @ANCHOFIJO=1      
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(ISNULL(#D.CODIGO_ITEM_PROVEEDOR,'''') as char(35)) AS CODIGO_ITEM_PROVEEDOR,'
            ELSE
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '''=T("'''+ '+ISNULL(#D.CODIGO_ITEM_PROVEEDOR,'''')+'+'''")'' AS CODIGO_ITEM_PROVEEDOR,'
                
        END

      --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON LA DESCRIPCION DEL ITEM
      IF @DESCRIPCION = 1
        BEGIN      
            IF @ANCHOFIJO=1         
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(ISNULL(#D.DESCRIPCION_ITEM,'''') as char(70)) AS DESCRIPCION_ITEM,' 
            ELSE
                SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'ISNULL(#D.DESCRIPCION_ITEM,'''') AS DESCRIPCION_ITEM,' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
        END

        --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS SE ACTUALIZA EL NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS
      IF @EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS = 1
         BEGIN
            UPDATE #DETALLE 
                SET NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS = SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(SE.DESCRIPCION))+' '+RTRIM(LTRIM(SE.DIRECCION)),0,71)
            FROM #DETALLE #DET WITH (NOLOCK)
                    INNER JOIN SITIO_ENTREGA SE WITH (NOLOCK)
                        ON SE.ID_EMPRESA = #DET.ID_CLIENTE 
                        AND SE.EAN_NAD_ITO_DP = #DET.EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS
            
            --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON EL EAN DEL LUGAR DONDE SE ENTREGAN LOS ITEMS Y SU NOMBRE
                IF @ANCHOFIJO=1 
                    SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(#D.EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS as char(35)),cast(ISNULL(#D.NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS,'''') as char(70)) AS NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS,'
                ELSE
                    SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '''=T("''+#D.EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS+''")'' AS EAN_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS, ISNULL(#D.NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS,'''') AS NOMBRE_LUGAR_ENTREGA_ITEMS,'
                    -- '''=T("''+#D.PLU+''")'' AS PLU,'
         END


        --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA LA CANTIDAD TOTAL SE ACTUALIZA LA CANTIDAD_TOTAL
      IF @CANTIDAD = 1      
         BEGIN
            UPDATE #DETALLE
                SET CANTIDAD_TOTAL = CASE CAST(SUBSTRING(STR(ISNULL(QTY.CANTIDAD, #IDMIN.CANTOTAL),16,3),CHARINDEX('.',STR(ISNULL(QTY.CANTIDAD, #IDMIN.CANTOTAL),16,3))+1,3) AS INT)
                                                    WHEN 0 THEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ISNULL(QTY.CANTIDAD, #IDMIN.CANTOTAL),16,0))),'')
                                                        ELSE ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(ISNULL(QTY.CANTIDAD, #IDMIN.CANTOTAL),16,3))),'') END
            FROM #DETALLE #DET WITH (NOLOCK)
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN OC_BO_V1_1.dbo.QTY_CANTIDAD QTY WITH (NOLOCK)
                        ON QTY.ID_ORDEN = #DET.ID_ORDEN
                        AND QTY.CONSECUTIVO = #DET.CONSECUTIVO
                INNER JOIN #IDMIN #IDMIN WITH (NOLOCK)
                    ON #DET.ID_DETALLE = #IDMIN.IDMINIMO
            WHERE QTY.ID_EMPRESA = @ID_EMPRESA                   
                    AND QTY.ID_TIPO_CANTIDAD = '21'
                            
            --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON LA CANTIDAD TOTAL
            IF @ANCHOFIJO=1
                    SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(ISNULL(#D.CANTIDAD_TOTAL,'''') as char(16)) AS CANTIDAD,'
                ELSE
                    SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '''=T("''+ISNULL(#D.CANTIDAD_TOTAL,'''')+''")'' AS CANTIDAD,' 
         END

        --SI EL CLIENTE CONFIGURA EL EAN_PUNTO_VENTA SE ACTUALIZA EL NOMBRE_PUNTO_VENTA
      IF @EAN_PUNTO_VENTA = 1      
         BEGIN
            UPDATE #DETALLE 
                SET NOMBRE_PUNTO_VENTA = SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(PV.DESCRIPCION))+' '+RTRIM(LTRIM(PV.DIRECCION)),0,71)
            FROM #DETALLE #DET WITH (NOLOCK)
                    INNER JOIN PUNTOVENTA PV WITH (NOLOCK)
                        ON PV.EAN_NAD_SN = #DET.EAN_PUNTO_VENTA 
                        AND PV.ID_EMPRESA = #DET.ID_CLIENTE                 
           
            --SE ARMA EL SELECT FINAL DE #DETALLE CON EL EAN DEL PUNTO DE VENTA Y SU NOMBRE
                IF @ANCHOFIJO=1
                    SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + 'cast(#D.EAN_PUNTO_VENTA as char(35)),cast(ISNULL(#D.NOMBRE_PUNTO_VENTA,'''') as char(70)) AS NOMBRE_PUNTO_VENTA,'
                ELSE
                    SET @STRSQL2 = @STRSQL2 + '''=T("''
```

ya valide el Collation de las bases de datos, de las tablas y de las columnas como se sugiere en diferentes lugares de Google que reportan este error, pero concuerdan con las configuraciones de origen.

Yo entiendo que se una posible solución, es colocar el Collation Modern_Spanish_CI_AS para que funcione, pero no se exactamente en que parte del código.

Si alguien me pudiera orientar, lo agradecería inmensamente.

Comment: Ni idea qué habrá en esas variables, pero lo que te está diciendo es que estás armando ese STRSQL2 con textos en collation diferente. Si salió de tablas esa data, significa que los campos están definidos con collation diferente. Faltaría más información de las tablas que usas (los DML) para poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, ya adjunte la mayoria del SP. no se si depronto con eos pudieras tener una mejor visión.

Comment: el error sale en esta parte:

      IF DESCRIPCION = 1
  BEGIN      
   IF ANCHOFIJO=1   
    SET STRSQL2 = STRSQL2 + 'cast(ISNULL(#D.DESCRIPCION_ITEM,'''') as char(70)) AS DESCRIPCION_ITEM,' 
   ELSE
    SET STRSQL2 = STRSQL2 + 'ISNULL(#D.DESCRIPCION_ITEM,'''') AS DESCRIPCION_ITEM,'
  END

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544392/how-to-fix-a-collation-conflict-in-a-sql-server-query